# Assembly Redirect from GAC with different minor Version

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, .net-assembly

We have a Reporting-Project using the Client-Version of SSRS, the RDLC-Files.
To do so, we use the Nuget-Package "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Windows" with the only version avaliable. The File-Version is "11.0.3452.0".
Everything works fine, but on ONE Server, when we install the "Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime CTP" into the GAC, File-Version "11.0.1443.3", these Assemblies are used and SubReports show the message

> Error: Subreport could not be shown.

From what I understood, it is the expected behavior, that the gac-assemblies with the same Major-Version are being priorized over the local ones.

Now the interesting Part: I inserted some Debugs to print out all loaded Assemblies:

```
protected void BtnAssemblies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<br />");

    var sbExceptions = new StringBuilder();
    sbExceptions.Append("<br />");

    var t = new LocalReport();

    var reportViewerAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i < reportViewerAssemblies.Count();i ++)
    {
        var ass = reportViewerAssemblies[i];

        try
        {
            sb.Append(ass.FullName);
            sb.Append(": ");
            sb.Append(ass.CodeBase);
            sb.Append("<br />");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            sbExceptions.Append(ass.FullName);
            sbExceptions.Append("<br />");
        }
    }

    var str = sb.ToString();
    str += "<br />";
    str += "<br />";

    str += sbExceptions.ToString();
    LblAssemblies.Text = str;
}
```

And except the 4 expected assemblies:

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.DLL
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.DLL
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.DLL
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.DLL

The loaded assemblies are exactly the same.
Since I have no clue, how this can happen, I tried to "fix-up" the problem by overwriting the binding, since I'd like to use the local assemblies anyway.
Since it's not possible to redirect the same version, I tried the File-Version:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.1443.3" newVersion="11.0.3452.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Which also doesn't work.
So my questions:

- How is it possible installing a different minor Version in the GAC
  causes ONE Server to fail?
- Is there any way to find out more about the assemblies loaded? Unfortunately, we don't get an error directly, just a meaningless Message
- As a workaround, is there any possibility to either overrule the GAC or put a redirect on the file-versiob